# Uploading a file to Azure blob in net core using Telerik control

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, telerik

Project using .net core 2.2, using Telerik controls trying to upload a file to an Azure blob.

I have a controller which expects the submitted model to have an IEnumerable of IFormFile.

When I try and read the file, it thinks the file exists in the directory the web app is in. I know the problem is I am using System.IO.Path.* but I am not sure of what to use.

My view includes this control:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" })
    .Validation(validation => validation.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".gif", ".jpg", ".png" }))
```

My controller method signature:

```
[CustomAuthorization]
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Content/AddFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(ViewModels.Content.ContentViewModel model)
{

}
```

And relevant code:

```
foreach (var formFile in model.files)
{
   if (formFile.Length > 0)
   {
       using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) // what is this FileMode.Create doing?
       {
           // I'm stuck here, where is this created?
           await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
       }
   }
}
```

I have a helper class where I do all of my uploading to Azure blob. It works, the method signature is:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveContent(string contentName, string contentType, Stream fileContents)
```

But I am not sure how to get a stream of the file and I am not sure what the FileMode.Create part is doing. Inside the SaveContent is where the file is created.

In short I am using the Telerik file control, and trying to get the contents of the selected file into a stream.

I am using this as a reference: https://www.telerik.com/forums/file-upload-full-example-with-server-side-code

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Blob storage ready ready for your files, we'll need to provide our application with a method for saving files. Since this application will use Telerik control with MVC views  for the client-side of the application, we'll need a WebAPI endpoint for client to communicate with. Let's create a controller and controller action for handling our file requests.

Suppose below is the controller :

```
//FileUploadController.cs

[Route("api/[controller]")]

public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("[Action]")]
    async public Task<IActionResult> SaveFile(IFormFile files)
    {
        // Connect to Azure

        // Save file to blob

        // Respond with success
    }
}
```

The FileUploadController will handle a SafeFile request at the endpoint api/FileUpload/SaveFile. By accepting a parameter of IFormFile we'll be able to bind the incoming files value from the request body. The HTTP request below is what a file request should look like to ASP.NET when the request is made.

```
Entity
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary*

Body
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="some-file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Next we'll connect to our Azure storage account and make a reference to the "photos" container we designated earlier as our storage for user photos. To work with Azure in .NET we'll add the WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet package. Once this package is installed we can make a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob giving us access to the Azure storage APIs.

// Connect to Azure

// Set the connection string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

// Create a blob client. 
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Get a reference to a container  
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("photos");

With the file and Azure container ready, we can save the file. We'll need a BlockBlobReference, this will create a new reference in Azure or allow us to overwrite an existing file. Next, we'll open a file stream and upload the file asnychronously to Azure.

// Save file to blob

// Get a reference to a blob  
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(files.FileName);

// Create or overwrite the blob with the contents of a local file 
using (var fileStream = files.OpenReadStream())
{
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Once the file has been uploaded to Azure, we can respond back to the HTTP request with a success response. In the response, we'll include the file name that was saved, the file size, and most importantly the URI where the file can be found in storage. Depending on how the feature is used in an application, we may want to save this URI into a database so that it can be used later in our application's UI.

```
// Respond with success
return Json(new {
    name = blockBlob.Name,
    uri = blockBlob.Uri,
    size = blockBlob.Properties.Length
});
```

Hope it resolve your query.

For further [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328488/kendo-ui-chunk-upload-to-microsoft-azure) .